# Android emulator open with empty screen

Tags: android, emulation

Android emulator open with empty screen

[image]

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

- Check that you have the latest version from `SDK Manager`.
- Try to delete it, then create a new device.
- Check if your GPU driver needs an update.

Answer (score 0):

Your GPU driver is not up to date,  try to update your GPU driver. Refer to the below image for updating the drivers.[image]